# Why is my menu order not working with wp_nav_menu?

Tags: walker, menus

I have a custom menu using the new Menu System but it is not returning in the correct order. I have no idea what order its in - its not alphabetical, or by date, or by any pattern I can see.

The link is http://www.oia.co.za/.

The pages "sponsors", "archives" and "fewtchafests" are supposed to appear as the last 3 items, after the series of numbers, not before them. If the first item wasn't also a number, I might think it was rendering all numbers last, but that first item ("8333") kind of scuppers that idea.

Screenshot of correctly dragged-and-dropped menu order attached, screenshot of website displaying wrong order attached, and the code used to call the menu is below.

[image: correct menu order]

[image]

```
    <!-- BEGIN ADVENT CALENDAR -->
    <nav role="navigation">
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'advent-calendar',
                'menu' => 'advent-calendar',
                'menu_class' => 'component-calendar',
                'container_id' => 'calendar',
                'container_class' => 'advent',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'walker'=> new Salamander_Advent_Walker()
                ) 
            );
        ?>
    </nav>
    <!-- END ADVENT CALENDAR -->
```

EDIT: It's definitely a problem with my custom walker (code below) - if I comment out the call to the custom walker function, it generates in the right order:

```
    class Salamander_Advent_Walker extends Walker_page {
        function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
           private $color_idx = 1;

            $advent_thumbnail = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-thumb', true);
            $advent_slug = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-slug', true);
            $advent_oneliner = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-oneliner', true);
            $advent_color = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-color', true);
            $advent_small_title = get_post_meta($item->object_id, 'advent-title', true);

            $advent_title = ( !empty($advent_small_title) ? $advent_small_title : $advent_slug);

            $output .= $indent . '
                        <li class="color'.$this->color_idx.' active">
                        <a href="#day'. $advent_slug .'">
                            <span class="day">
                                <strong>'. $advent_slug .'</strong>
                                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="content">
                                <small class="'. $advent_color .'">'. $advent_title .'</small>
                                <img src="'. $advent_thumbnail .'" width="126" height="91" alt="advent" />
                                <strong>'. $advent_oneliner .'</strong>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    ';
            $this->color_idx++;
            if ($this->color_idx > 4) {
                $this->color_idx = 1;
            }
        } // ends function
    } // ends class
```

Comment: Do you have a custom menu *defined* AND *assigned* to this `theme_location`, or is the output being generated by the fallback?

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, custom menu defined and location assigned.

Comment: okay, next step: remove the custom walker argument, and verify whether the menu renders properly or not. If it *does*, then the problem is your custom walker.

Comment: :) Yes, it's definitely the walker (and you have me thinking "Why didn't I think of that myself?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*AFAIK* there's a non-documented `orderby` parameter, that can be set to `menu_order`.

**Edit:** Straight from core, inside `/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` Line# 195 (WP 3.3.1):

```
$sorted_menu_items = array();
foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item )
    $sorted_menu_items[$menu_item->menu_order] = $menu_item;
```

It's the lines immediately before the Walker runs. So the set `menu_order` should affect the order. You'll just have to set it inside your page from the meta box.

[image]

In short: You shouldn't need a custom Walker at all.

Sidnotes:

- You don't have to use that `$indent`. It make really no sense as it's only for the source code.
- You don't have to make it that hard to save your meta data into single vars. Also would this add lots of queries if they're currently not cached. Do it the following way:

  ```
  extract( get_post_custom( $item->object_id ), EXTR_SKIP );
  ```

**Edit:** `extract` simply makes single variables out of your custom meta data. The `key` is then the new name of your variable. `EXTR_SKIP` cares about making the variables unique as it skips double keys.

```
// Example: Structure of your post custom/meta data
Array( 
    [0] => array( 'example_key_name' => array( 'example_value' ) )
    [1] => array( 'another_key_name' => 'another_value' )
)
// Becomes:
$example_key_name = array( 0 => 'example_value' );
// Value can now be called as:
$example_key_name[0];
// Becomes:
$another_key_name = 'another_value';
// Value can be called as:
$another_key_name
```

The last example is not really possible, as you normally got serialized arrays as custom values (even for single values). So you'll always have to append `[0]` to your variable. But this technique def. shortens code. Especially if you got really large sets of meta data per post/CPT.

Comment: Thanks - I've included the `orderby` parameter, but it didn't change anything. Thanks for the note about `$indent` (I do like my source-code to look neat, but that's just because I'm anal). How do I use the `extract()` function, or rather, how do I assign variables like `$advent_thumbnail` etc for use later if I use `extract()`?

Comment: @Amanda See (both) edits.

Comment: @Amanda Still following?

Comment: Hi - thanks, I understand the `extract` now... regarding not needing a custom walker - I had thought that would be the easiest way to retrieve a bunch of custom meta for display? `"You'll just have to set it inside your page from the meta box."` My home page isn't actually a "page", so there is no custom meta box to set menu order - the site is set to display "Latest Posts" in the settings, and this odd front page is managed by home.php.

Comment: @Amanda I didn't talk about the "home"-page, but about the menu_order for pages (see edit/added screenshot). We can see from the above screenshot of yours, that you're using the "pages"-post-type, so you can set the order there. This will affect the order directly as I wrote in the code-quote from the core file.

Comment: Oh right, I understand - no, I had already set the menu order explicitly as well, no change in display order.

Comment: Could you go into core, and add `echo '<pre>'; print_r($sorted_menu_items); echo '</pre>';` right below the lines I quoted from core ↑, then reload the page and post the result here? Thanks.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4DepMXVH Its very long :) but it is in the correct order there...

Comment: The only thing that is affecting the order afterwards is the walker. Try to add `__return_zero` or `__return_false` for the `walker` argument.